# Log Sql errors Cakephp

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I am using a Plugin to log the errors and warnings in a Cakephp-Application, and it is working as it supposed, but I was thinknig ,if the Connection with my DB is not working well, then still I need to log these errors , but this time in an external file, 
The Idea should be easy, I call CaeLog::write() and in these Method(wich has been reimplemented by the Plugin) I would put "try/Catch", which would help me in the case an Exception is thrown, to write the message to a logfile.
My bootstrap.php looks like this :`
App::uses('CakeLog', 'Log');

```
CakeLog::config('debug', array(
        'engine' => 'File',
        'types' => array('notice', 'info', 'debug'),
        'file' => 'debug',
));

CakeLog::config('fileLog', array(
        'engine' => 'File',
        'types' => array('fileLog'),
        'file' => 'fileLog',
        'scopes' => array('fileLog')
));
 CakeLog::config('default', array(
'engine' => 'DatabaseLogger.DatabaseLog',
'types' => array('warning', 'error', 'critical', 'alert', 'emergency')`
```

In the write methode i have this Code

```
function write($type, $message){
        try {

               //Save In Db
        } catch (Exception $exc) {
//If the save in DB fails call log in fileLog(which has been defined in bootstrap.php)
            CakeLog::write('fileLog', "***************************\n".$exc."\n***************************\n");
        }     
}
```

The problem now : I am getting a loop, cause of the call in the catch block, which is trying again to save in db, how could i solve this without a loop?

Comment: Why is your current setup preventing you from logging DB Connection errors?

Comment: It is not, I was thinkning , sometimes the db will not be available, in this case , I need to log it into a file, there is an Exception Handler too, but with it I am going to log every exception, but I am finding no DB/SqlExceptionfor this specific case

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Every error is an error, if you log one you can log all, unless you're actually logging *in* the db, which you don't mention.

Comment: Ok what about the case you are having two types of errors ?? NullException and MathematicalExceptions(Say divideByZero) how can i specify that automatically, that both will be logged in two different files in the config ? is that possible ?? I just don't think that having all the errors in the same file is a good idea

Comment: Logging in files is a bad idea in general as it is the slowest method, especially for bigger applications. Do you want to split log files based on the type of error? What version are you on?

Comment: I have edited the question again